# InAppPurchase doesnt work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

Im making a game and i got the problem:
every time i'm making a purchase in it, it returns me Failed transaction.
I call this function to start transaction:

```
func buyProduct() {
    let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
}
```

I got several users in SandBox-testers and set price for in-app-purchase for free.
What's the problem?

```
var product: SKProduct!
//used in viewDidLoad

SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
self.getProductInfo()

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
      let products = response.products
      if (products.count != 0){
           product = products[0] as! SKProduct
      }
}

func getProductInfo() {
      if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
           let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "id.unique")
           let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
           request.delegate = self
           request.start()
      }

}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
      for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
           if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState{
                case .Purchased:
                     self.removeAds()
                     println("success")
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                     break
                case .Failed:
                     println("failed")
                     showAlert("Error", message: "Ooops, there is transaction problem")
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                     break
                case .Restored:
                     println("restored")
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                     break
                default:
                     break
                }
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with a configuration of your products in iTunes Connect? Thanks

Comment: Check your bundle identifier and product identifier. Then double check product identifier sent to apple server for purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you test on real device?

In app purchase do not work on simulator, it will be failed with error like this.

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x7f98b8fda180 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

Answer (score 0):

IAP works on simulator 6.0 and above, not below (I assume it's positive for you because you are using Swift).

Usually, you need exact error info to decide what's preventing this. There is an error property in transaction object, and it has localizedDescription which will tell you the exact problem.

Modify below statement to reflect that info, or simply use NSLog to report the error in console. If nothing, you can simply break on that statement and check for value of transaction.error.localizedDescription.

```
showAlert("Error", message: "Ooops, there is transaction problem")
```

Error can be sometimes as simple as different country store than your iphone settings (in which case your next transaction will succeed without you doing anything), and sometimes may have non-sandbox user signed in on your iphone settings.

Even though you don't have error info, some questions to ask are:

- Simple check: Are all your contracts signed in itunesconnect?
- Most Likely cause: Are you having a valid SKProduct object inside `buyProduct()` function? You have not implemented [SKRequestDelegate's didFailWithError](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKRequestDelegate/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008416-CH1-SW4) method in your code - which can tell you what's wrong with your product request. If you do not begin payment with a valid product, purchase is destined to fail. And there is no way to construct valid SKProduct except for `request.start`, followed by successful `didReceiveResponse`.

If you need step by step tutorial on how to integrate IAP - here is [my own tutorial](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/make-money-appstore-ios-in-app-purchase-tutorial/) and a [video lecture series](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-ios-moneymaking-course-learn-in-app-purchases/?couponCode=PROMO29SO) with SWIFT and Objective C. It also accompanies code sample for SWIFT and Objective C.